# Is profile guided optimization possible with shared libraries in gcc?

Tags: gcc, profiling, shared-libraries, compiler-optimization

I recently rolled out a new Toolchain on Linux, with gcc 4.5.0 and binutils 2.20 with gold. Now I was curious about this new thing PGO. While it's clear how it works with executables, I've not been able to find an answer on shared libraries. I found two unanswered posts on the gcc mailing list via google, that's all.

So here's what I tried:
As long as I don't flag -fprofile-generate everything is well and my .so is dlopen()'ed by the main program and works flawlessly.
When compiled and linked with -fprofile-generate the library gets loaded, everything works, but when I end the main program I get a sigsegv with coredump.

I fed the corefile to gdb and got this:

```
#0 0x00000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1 0x1f32bc2f in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

And of course no .cdda files are saved.

Any ideas?

Philipp

Comment: How did you run GDB?  I am guessing you did this: "gdb core".  Do this instead: "gdb exename core".  Chances are, you'll get a more meaningful stack trace.  Alternatively, run the executable under GDB from the start: "gdb exename" then "run".

Comment: gdb exename core was exactly how I ran gdb.

Answer (score 1):

I build a shared library with PGO.

What I do is to build a "profile" directory with all the .o files with profile-generate. Then I link those into a shared library. Then I do a profiling run with the library linked to an executable also built with profile-generate.

After that I build a "release" directory with all the .o files built with profile-use, link those into a shared library and I have a shared library built with PGO.

Comment: So, this way you create 2 profile files - one for the shared object, and one for the executable, right? Do you pass them somehow as command-line argument to gcc? Or gcc finds them and uses them automatically (if created in the default directory and default name)?